# Entity framework Code First SQL Server View

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, view, ef-code-first

I defined a view in my DB and then I wrote the entity definition in the code:

```
    [Persistence]
    [Table("ADMV_APPLICATION_OPTION")]
    public partial class ADMV_APPLICATION_OPTION
    {
        public string ID_APPLICATION_OPTION { get; set; }
        public string DS_APPLICATION_OPTION { get; set; }
        public byte FL_TYPE { get; set; }
        public Nullable<double> OPTION_NUM_VALUE { get; set; }
        public string OPTION_STR_VALUE { get; set; }
        public string OPTION_XML_VALUE { get; set; }
        public System.Guid GUID_DIVISION_SAP { get; set; }
        public string ID_DIVISION_SAP { get; set; }
        public string ID_PLANT { get; set; }
    }
```

When I execute my application I get the error

> One or more validation errors were detected during model generation:
>
> MES.Core.ADMV_APPLICATION_OPTION: : EntityType
>   'ADMV_APPLICATION_OPTION' has no key defined. Define the key for this
>   EntityType.

Do I need a key also for the views?

thanks

Comment: You need add PrimaryKey ,Entity Framework needs to know the key.

Comment: Also for the views?

Comment: Yes views also need PK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error clearly tell that you need add PrimaryKey. Views in EntityFramework also need PK. You can tell EF, some column may be used as PK, using `ISNULL` when you create view in SQL:

```
Create view SomeView
As
  Select 
      IsNull(YourUniqueId, -1) as YourUniqueId,
      ...
  From TableName
```

Or using Data Annotation use `[Key]` attribute, setting this attribute to `ID_APPLICATION_OPTION` be sure it is unique.

```
    [Persistence]
    [Table("ADMV_APPLICATION_OPTION")]
    public partial class ADMV_APPLICATION_OPTION
    {
        [Key]
        public string ID_APPLICATION_OPTION { get; set; }
        public string DS_APPLICATION_OPTION { get; set; }
        public byte FL_TYPE { get; set; }
        public Nullable<double> OPTION_NUM_VALUE { get; set; }
        public string OPTION_STR_VALUE { get; set; }
        public string OPTION_XML_VALUE { get; set; }
        public System.Guid GUID_DIVISION_SAP { get; set; }
        public string ID_DIVISION_SAP { get; set; }
        public string ID_PLANT { get; set; }
    }
```